# Javascript variable acts like reference instead of object

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, reference, slickgrid

I have an issue I can't quite put my finger on.

```
var records = dataView.getItems();

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var date = records[i].RecordCreated;
    records[i].RecordCreated = new Date(parseInt(date.replace('/Date(', '')));
}

records = JSON.stringify(records);
```

This is a small loop that takes existing data from a SlickGrid dataview and converts the /Date(###)/ format to a proper date format in order to be deserialized on the server.  This works fine.

The weird issue is that the `var records = dataView.getItems();` definition is acting more like a reference than an individual, unique, object.  Consider the following code:

```
var records = dataView.getItems();

// Debug Code [A]
console.log(records);
console.log(dataView.getItems());

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var date = records[i].RecordCreated;
    records[i].RecordCreated = new Date(parseInt(date.replace('/Date(', '')));
}

// Debug Code [B]
console.log(records);
console.log(dataView.getItems());

records = JSON.stringify(records);
```

The console logs at [B] are both identical, where one would expect them to be different.  Meaning instead of seeing the second log with unchanged /Date(###)/ format dates, proper date objects are printing.

Even stranger is that at [A] the console logs are printing as if the loop ran asynchronously and finished prior to the console.log() command was called.

This is all wrapped in a function with some conditional statements to do different loops, nothing crazy.  What I need to know is how/why the `records` definition is not working as per usual (a unique variable in memory, that can be edited without affecting the original object).

**Solution**

---

So the problem was that records was receiving the original object from the SlickGrid library.  What I did to fix the issue was clone the object before assigning it to records.

Clone function:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (obj == null || typeof (obj) != 'object')
        return obj;
    var temp = new obj.constructor();
    for (var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    return temp;
}
```

Usage:

```
var __data = dataView.getItems();
records = clone(__data);
```

Hope this helps anybody else viewing this question in the future.

Comment: When you expand those logged arrays in the console, do you see a message "Object state below is captured at first expansion"?

Comment: @DCoder Would that be somewhere in the prototype expansion?  I do not see that message anywhere in the expected object's expanded view.

Comment: It's usually shown as a blue "i" icon next to the object, but in this case it's not the real problem. According to the source of SlickGrid, Caleb's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like your `records` variable is an array being returned from `dataView.getItems()`.  This variable IS a reference to the array object, so changing things on that object will be reflected in all the references to the object.

Comment: I didn't know you could declare a variable as a reference like that in javascript.  I really need to dig into the intricacies of this language a little at some point...thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that `dataView.getItems()` calls `Array.protototype.slice` on any collection it is returning